# Optimising fetching of data from different shards for a user

Tags: postgresql, nosql, system-design

Lets say i have sharded data based on order_id and now if i want to show order history for a user_id, it would require to fetch data from all shards to get all orders, which in turn seems to be costly operation.

Are there some approaches to fetch order history efficiently in this case.
One approach i am thinking is about:
To have another table that keeps all order_id's associated with that user and then fetching details for those order_id's from DB. But this will require multiple queries to be fired.

Are there any other approaches you could suggest or point to to optimise this?

Comment: Rule one of sharding a database: don't do it so you have to query across the boundaries.

Comment: Why would you shard some orders over different databases? How many trillion orders do you have? A couple of billion records is not something special for a database

Comment: single table fetch of some entries from a billion rows wont have latency impact on RDS(postgres)?